# PHP Mostrar datos aleatorios de una tabla sin que se repitan PHP

Tags: php, html, mysqli, phpmyadmin, php7

Tengo una tabla llamada "areas" con más de 100 filas y quisiera mostrar de manera aleatoria 9 resultados sin que se repitan, ¿cuál sería el código PHP?

Intenté con:

```
$slx1_a = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM areas ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;");
$slx1_q = mysqli_fetch_array($slx1_a);

$slx2_a = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM areas ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;");
$slx2_q = mysqli_fetch_array($slx2_a);

$slx3_a = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM areas ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;");
$slx3_q = mysqli_fetch_array($slx3_a);

$slx4_a = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM areas ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;");
$slx4_q = mysqli_fetch_array($slx4_a);

$slx5_a = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM areas ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;");
$slx5_q = mysqli_fetch_array($slx5_a);

$slx6_a = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM areas ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;");
$slx6_q = mysqli_fetch_array($slx6_a);

$slx7_a = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM areas ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;");
$slx7_q = mysqli_fetch_array($slx7_a);

$slx8_a = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM areas ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;");
$slx8_q = mysqli_fetch_array($slx8_a);

$slx9_a = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM areas ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;");
$slx9_q = mysqli_fetch_array($slx9_a);
```

Y muestro el resultado con:

```
echo $slx1_q['title'];
```

Pero se repiten los resultados y quisiera que no se repitieran.

Gracias.

Comment: Prueba a crear solo una query de esta manera: `$slx1_a = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM areas ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9;");
$slx1_q = mysqli_fetch_array($slx1_a);`

Comment: Gracias, pero cómo muestro los resultados?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacer 1 query en vez de 9:

```
$slx1_a = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM areas ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9;");
```

Para mostrar los resultados puedes hacerlo así:

```
while($slx1_q = mysqli_fetch_array($slx1_a))
{
    echo $slx1_q['title'];
}
```

**EDIT:**

Para mostrar los resultados pero en lista lo puedes hacer así:

```
while($slx1_q = mysqli_fetch_array($slx1_a))
{
    echo '<ul>
              <li type="circle">'.$slx1_q['title'].'</li>
         </ul>';
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!!! Ya puedo mostrar los resultados sin que se repitan, solo una pregunta más, ¿cómo puedo enlistar cada resultado en <li></li>???  Gracias Mario.

Comment: @Tom he editado mi respuesta para que te lo muestre con lista. A ver si te sirve